# erro ao fazer o enable-migrations no visual studio em um projeto de mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando conectar meu projeto no meu banco local.

> [image: Linha com a connectstring e o banco de dados[1]]

e minha connect string está abaixo.

> `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-QEGG9P00;Initial Catalog=Portal_Recarga_Virtual;Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

porem ao fazer o enable-migrations o VS retorna ao erro abaixo:

> "An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure."

o detalhe e que o serviço do sql server está ativo.

> [image: serviço sql]

voces podem me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque o usuário e a sua senha ... é isso.

Comment: não de certo crie o perfil abaixo e nada.    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-QEGG9P00;Initial Catalog=Portal_Recarga_Virtual;Integrated Security=False;User ID=igorss;Password=teste;;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />